# Goodness-of-fit of model derived from multivariate logistic regression

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, multivariate-regression

I have a question regarding the relationship between the value of Chi square and df in determining the goodness-of-fit in a model derived from multivariate logistic regression. If the N= 290, Chi square =26.57, p=0.003 in a model with 16 variables (df is not reported), can one tell if this is legit or would this model represent overfitting or multicollinearity? Hope that makes sense. I really appreciate any help in making sense of these results.

Comment: This result actually represents overdispersion/underfitting if I'm not mistaken.  The degrees of freedom is the number of *unique covariate patterns* minus the number of betas.  The overall sample size doesn't matter.

Comment: Many thanks probabilityislogic. So if I understand correctly, the value of Chi should be closer to (16-betas). Is there a definition of what value of Chi represents optimal fit and is there a method to correct for overdispersion?

Comment: Chi should be closer to the degrees of freedom, which is given by $n-p$ where $n$ is the number of unique $x$ values and $p$ is the number of betas.

Comment: Thanks probablityislogic. What are the optimum values of Chi-square Pearson/df and Ch square Deviance/df? I know they should be close to 1, but how "close" is close enough? Would 1.5 be considered close? Or would 0.95 be considered close? Thanks again. Sorry to belabor the point.